# BLE Advertise 32-bit Service-UUID in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-ble, android-8.0-oreo

I have a small app which just performs a BLE Advertising. 
The app runs on a **Nexus 5x with Android 8.0**

This is the code to start BLE advertising:

```
private fun startAdvertising() {
    val serviceUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString("DAB5D1DC-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

    val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .addServiceUuid(serviceUuid)
            .build()

    val settings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .build()

    bluetoothLeAdvertiser!!.startAdvertising(settings, data, advertiserCallback)
}
```

The advertising starts, but the payload is wrong. On **Pre**-Android 8.0 devices we receive the correct service-uuid when scan for this messages with a 2nd device:

```
32-bit Service-UUID: 0xDAB5D1DC
```

But when I start the advertisements on my Nexus 5x with Android 8.0, I receive an incorrect service-uuid:

```
32-bit Service-UUID: 0x0000D1DC
```

For the BLE scanning part I use the nrf Connect app from playstore.

Everything works as expected, if I advertise a common 128-bit Service UUID and not an 32-bit one.

Are there any changes for Android 8.0 regarding my issue?

**Update 2017-08-28:**

Same issue on a Nexus 6P. Created an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65099899

Answer (score 0):

Use only ParcelUuid.fromString("DAB5D1DC")
this will make youre packet smaller.
youre problem is probably because youre advertise packet too big i think the max is 32 bytes.

Comment: No, it's really a bug in Android. Have a look at the issue and it's already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Create **Constants**

```
 public static final UUID serviceUuid = UUID.fromString("DAB5D1DC-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

and than

```
 val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
        .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(Constants.serviceUuid))
        .build()
```

Comment: in the receiving end, i am not able to receive the UUID,